# Unable to use add_basemap in contextily

Tags: python

I am using python 3.8 on anaconda. I have successfully downloaded contextily module however, when im using add_basemap function,  the following error occurs:

AttributeError: module 'contextily' has no attribute 'add_basemap'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I fixed it by reinstalling contextily. So just remove it and reinstall it.

```
conda remove contextily
conda install contextily
```